# python opencv Failed to allocate 294511099035648 bytes in function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

src = input("enter the local path of the image the you want to resize: ")
img_old = cv2.imread(rf"{src}", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

height, width, no_of_channels = img_old.shape
print("The size of the original image is : ", height, "x", width, "(height x width)")
time.sleep(1)

scale = int(input("Enter how much percentage that you want to resize your image, example-50 (decreases by 50%), 200(increases by 200%) : "))
scale = scale/100
scaled_image = cv2.resize(img_old, None, fx= int(scale*width), fy= int(scale*height), interpolation= cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
cv2.imwrite('newimage.png', scaled_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

```
enter the local path of the image the you want to resize: C:\Users\dheer\Desktop\pythonProjects\ImageResizer\supercar.jpg
The size of the original image is :  3632 x 5456 (height x width)
Enter how much percentage that you want to resize your image, example-50 (decreases by 50%), 200(increases by 200%) : 50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dheer\Desktop\pythonProjects\ImageResizer\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    scaled_image = cv2.resize(img_old, None, fx= int(scale*width), fy= int(scale*height), interpolation= cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 294511099035648 bytes in function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'
```

Comment: 294511099035648 bytes is over 260 TB (if we count 1024 as steps, it's 267.85TB; and if we use 1000s, then it's 294.5TB).

Answer (score 2):

fx and fy are not new x and new y but scale factor. This means that you want to scale x by `50/100*5456`, thus making new x equal `5456 * (50/100*5456)`. And the same with y.

Fix is to only pass scale as fx and fy:

```py
scaled_image = cv2.resize(img_old, None, fx=scale, fy=scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Or use the second argument only to pass desired size:

```py
scaled_image = cv2.resize(img_old, (int(scale*width), int(scale*height)), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html

Answer (score 0):

**fx** = number of times image will scale in **x** direction.
**fy** = number of times image will scale in **y** direction.

if **fx=2** and **fy=2** then image will becomes **2 times** of original image.
(height and width pixels gets doubled).

when you pass **50 as resize percentage** then **fx becomes 2728** that means **new image will be 2728 times of original image** and this is causing **memeory error**. And the similar thing happens for fy value.

*so your code need modification as below.*

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

src = input("enter the local path of the image the you want to resize: ")
img_old = cv2.imread(rf"{src}", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

height, width, no_of_channels = img_old.shape
print("The size of the original image is : ", height, "x", width, "(height x width)")
time.sleep(1)

scale = int(input("Enter how much percentage that you want to resize your image, example-50 (decreases by 50%), 200(increases by 200%) : "))
scale = scale/100
scaled_image = cv2.resize(img_old, None, fx= int(scale), fy= int(scale), interpolation= cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
cv2.imwrite('newimage.png', scaled_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```